# removeUpdates was called but location icon is still showing

Tags: android

I start locating GPS updates in main activity `OnResume` method and finish in `OnPause` using `removeUpdates`. As soon as application starts location icon is shown in status bar. But it never hides after this.
My application has the single activity and uses Google Maps. Where the issue might be?

Comment: does it ever turns off? after a while or never?

Comment: My code never receiving updates after `removeUpdates`. May be map is still using it...

Comment: I was refering to the location icon.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY) about network hardware on android device, the GPS works the same way. 
Basiclly it takes a lot more power to turn it off then to use it, so the system keeps it alive for a little longer in case someone else would like to use.